# Windshield motor with ATX power supply keeps shutting down

Tags: power-supply, motor, dc-motor, atx

I need to connect my windshield motor (12V) to my ATX power supply from old computer. I've tested the motor on my bench power supply and i draws around 1,5A @ 12V, so it should be well in range of the supply capabilities. But when i power the supply (PS_ON wire to ground) and connect my motor, the supply instantly shuts down.

I think the short protection circuit of the supply may be kicking in, but I'm not quite sure - the motor has very low resistance. ('cause it's a coil)

What do you think? Can adding some capacitors in parallel might help?

Comment: You motor is likely to pull several amps when starting. Look-up the term "inrush current".

Comment: You should limit the current that goes to the motor. You are definitely activating the over-current protection on your supply. PCs never start with an extreme inrush on the 12V. Also, what is the amount of amps written on your supply's 12V line?

Comment: @NatsuKage on 12V rail there is 38 Amps. Ok, what is my options for limiting inrush current in this situation?

Comment: @Kralik_011  You can do it quite a few ways. Either limit the current using a large size resistor, or make a current limiting circuit using voltage regulators. Or just plainly do a PWM motor control. All depends on what you're willing to pay and lose in space.

Comment: You might get away with just a resistor of 0.4-0.5Ohms. That would limit the current to 12/0.4 = 30A. In normal operation you would lose 1.5*0.4 = 0.6Volts from the 12V. Your resistor will consume 360Watt but only very shortly when starting. Whatever you use (e.g. wind your own) beware of that. Nominal it will consume ~1W. (I did not know an ATX can supply 38Amps on 12V, must be a big 600W supply...) The nice thing is that you can try at very low cost. Just find a long extension wire which is ~0.4 Ohm.

Comment: @Oldfart thanks, but i need it to be somewhat reliable, so DIY my solution.. eh, i don't know if i trust myself so much :D. What about NTC thermistor? from what I've found i can only use up to 10 amps... What about PWM? would this help? Smoothing capacitors?

Comment: are you absolutely certain that the power supply can provide 38 A on the +12 V output?